# Как отключить NavigationView в приложение когда юзер выбрал BotBar

Tags: android, android-navigation-view

Юзер межет выбрать не шторку и меню внизу, но поскольку NavView в main.xml
он не заполняеться но если слайдить то он вылазит

Подскажите как сделать его Disable ?

```
navView.isActive = false - не раробает
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, еще не хватает опыта и знаний правильно гуглить